# Flutter Dart - Provider isnt workin'. Just white screen

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying add some ads to my app and I'm using provider plugin. I don't know lots about this and I need help.
My problem is my app is just white screen instead of loading screen.
My code is lookin' like this:

```
import 'package:distance_meter/ad_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'pages/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  final _instanceOfYourProvider = Provider();

  runApp(


  Provider<Provider>.value(
    value: _instanceOfYourProvider,
    builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(home: Loading()),
  )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it seems that you want to provide `AdState` to your app. If that's the case, you do not need the `final _instanceOfYourProvider = Provider();` at all and you should provide `AdState` to the app like this:

```
runApp(
  Provider<AdState>.value(
    value: adState,
    child: MaterialApp(home: Loading()),
  )
);
```

No magic there, just plain Provider documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/provider